# PHP mail function doesnt work - XAMPP enviroment

Tags: php, xampp, smtp, sendmail, mail-server

So i have basic code in my maling.php file to send email, but with no luck - always returns "Mailing failed"

```
<?php
$emailTo = "{mymail}@gmail.com";
$subject = "This should work";
$body = "Hellou mark mun";
$headers = "From: {mysecondmail}@gmail.com";
if (mail($emailTo,$subject,$body,$headers)){
    echo "Email was send";
}else{
    echo "Mailing failed";
}
?>
```

I have tried to change configuration in my sendmail.ini and php.ini file as stated in many tutorials, but it didnt work so now my files contains just this:

```
;php.ini
SMTP=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
sendmail_from = {mymail}@gmail.com
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

and

```
;sendmail.ini
[sendmail]

smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username={mymail}@gmail.com
auth_password={mypass}
```

If i run this with configuration and code as stated above i will get this messages in debug.log:

```
18/10/23 13:14:52 ** --- MESSAGE BEGIN ---
18/10/23 13:14:52 ** To: gazchamber.music@gmail.com
18/10/23 13:14:52 ** Subject: This should work
18/10/23 13:14:52 ** From: marekpatras@seznam.cz
18/10/23 13:14:52 ** 
18/10/23 13:14:52 ** Hellou mark mun
18/10/23 13:14:52 ** --- MESSAGE END ---
18/10/23 13:14:54 ** Connecting to smtp.gmail.com:587
18/10/23 13:14:54 ** Connected.
18/10/23 13:14:54 << 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP l11-v6sm1398703wrn.61 - gsmtp<EOL>
18/10/23 13:14:54 >> EHLO Lenovo-PC<EOL>
18/10/23 13:14:54 << 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [89.176.232.140]<EOL>250-SIZE 35882577<EOL>250-8BITMIME<EOL>250-STARTTLS<EOL>250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES<EOL>250-PIPELINING<EOL>250-CHUNKING<EOL>250 SMTPUTF8<EOL>
18/10/23 13:14:54 ** Authenticating as gazchamber.music@gmail.com
18/10/23 13:14:54 >> STARTTLS<EOL>
18/10/23 13:14:54 << 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS<EOL>
18/10/23 13:14:54 >> QUIT<EOL>
18/10/23 13:14:54 <<  5  1[Ď®»˘Ĺ“5Ô3p   +şňźşŚ@Î.đ<¤-ť˝dĂ”  /   ˙   #  ó ď ě †0‚‚0‚j aŚČĐ‚LÔ0
    *†H†÷
 0T10   UUS10U
Google Trust Services1%0#UGoogle Internet Authority G30
181009130800Z
190101130800Z0h10   UUS10U
California10U
Mountain View10U

Google LLC10Usmtp.gmail.com0‚"0
    *†H†÷
 ‚ 0‚
‚ ćŃ—P™Ĺ@Ę¸PJeJíŹK9tąLnFdÝťšl¨T]”›íĐđi1=*xpŃ?Ą_ţxŞWŇĚ#±~ÎJż‡ď›FÝ,,Ä˘ż…ČŹçĺźxMÄžľCYP‚"eÂéJe&Ř-wVůŇB‹0Ë˝ŹŞŻKäĂ˘źŤ&­łS¨ tşs›Ťz÷G…ÓîĎ…Kâ‘|Â)ťfśN˘1k^'ÜŽfąVôn
—gAňŞđ«Ô†s›(ŹŃíg“ştçËYűĐIDô+;ţ`ęqńH°Ýn23ÍżĄřW$c«    —†ăo±ßť€Jn(jjá\ÄfěˇÁ Ł‚B0‚>0U%0
+0U0‚smtp.gmail.com0h+\0Z0-+0†!http://pki.goog/gsr2/GTSGIAG3.crt0)+0†http://ocsp.pki.goog/GTSGIAG30UűâíDłëüýud€\Ś“ŮÝŚ0U˙0 0U#0€wÂ¸Pšgvv±-Â†Đ ~¦~şK0!U 00
+Öy0g01U*0(0& $ "† http://crl.pki.goog/GTSGIAG3.crl0
    *†H†÷
 ‚ ľ%Ú{Ĺ=$ń˘YEź/˝=FŢ9bžwŔ…§ˇŕăî>ÝÂ i-¶Ó»ü$ qÍň+áhŞź«w ďü9Gß¸‘ ×Ń‡
5Ř/ŻüQyG8Ä°Ř    aC$ds¶ŃćhTľĚ`3 ˘…]MĐNXe‚EfËM—´´ŽkIţ‡[])Rář~6Úgë
_D[Y0ńĂ™Ĺ=$‰ű/říř{ć§#j:Ś:ŰÚ9ţIÝŃ&¨zćµÉůÚ|Ť4“•ŢKÂ js"¬Nf,ŇM‡Đ/|…mĎ‹ĂU ć˙“’ő™ęŢIÖ‚XÝBOIňk=ş~Ë.ö»>ł€W `0‚\0‚D 
ă©0ür8?šS0
    *†H†÷
 0L1 0UGlobalSign Root CA - R210U

GlobalSign10U
GlobalSign0
170615000042Z
211215000042Z0T10   UUS10U
Google 
18/10/23 13:14:54 << Trust Services1%0#UGoogle Internet Authority G30‚"0<CR>    *†H†÷<CR> ‚ 0‚
‚ ĘRKę˙Î$k¨ÚrhŐV]HZ-5   vZĎ¤Č±©ţS‰ű­4˙[ź»çč Ü5su­ł±ą¤}+&yÎ@
ďQ¸ź2Ś|p†RKţj'kć6zbPŘßš‰Ě   )ëO)€Ź8€j|˝—;x}EI6OAÍ˘ŕvW<h1ydÉn×QfĂ˘d,yŔçeĂV„SZCmËš ŇďiŃ°ťs˘ŕ*`eP1Ďűł/ż@.µI
nÜ—úż,ź9XTŻ–čĹŽĽ¨MAĹ“‘˘ˇ‹ňţÁ$IŁGKĹÝ§Wib+ëţ ďiű:Ąđ~)îí–÷± ä%ŕ3 Ł‚30‚/0U˙†0U%0++0U˙0˙ 0UwÂ¸Pšgvv±-Â†Đ ~¦~şK0U#0€›âWgŔjŢY´š-ßÜ†.05+)0'0%+0†http://ocsp.pki.goog/gsr202U+0)0' % #†!http://crl.pki.goog/gsr2/gsr2.crl0?U 80604g0*0(+https://pki.goog/repository/0
    *†H†÷
 ‚ ·‰–äSí»ěŰ¨2ź,ŁÍm­Bwł¸ćÉR` {W'Ćµ?g
™,[ZĘ"
Ýž»KH?Ź=‹!„Emő˙¬h‰ÍdâÖÖ^@ÂŽ*÷ďÓ6¤@0ő2’vű~žSęÂvü9­ţf’&éÄ8ÍIúC‡đ]ÖVM×ńÂÝ°MţĂ*n|źn\íbB™á÷6îŚ, ăF—ZwŔ ĆJý@"‡rZęśĄÇZŚä¤}ą„5_‰6V@=č»5ríŻVN°».©›äű>cČ›K‘DfWŔ´–đÜ,W?R­•Ş}MĐňźś@čÖUsş<ßË [!gÂí2Ţ    
18/10/23 13:14:54 <<  F
18/10/23 13:14:54 ** Disconnected.
18/10/23 13:14:54 ** Disconnecting from smtp.gmail.com:587
18/10/23 13:14:54 ** Disconnected.
18/10/23 13:14:54 ** Disconnected.
18/10/23 13:14:54 ** Connection Closed Gracefully.
```

I tried nearly everything i found:

- Disabling modem and windows firewall
- Tried multiple ports 465,587,25
- Tried multiple mail servers (other than gmail)
- Changed properties of my php and sendmail files to run as administrator and have tried to run them in compatibility mode
- When i made changes to config files i have restarted Apache
- Tried multiple configuration file (default XAMPP with changes, creating one from scratch..)
  Do anyone have any clue what can cause this ? Error log changes just slightly it logs: "Connection Closed Gracefully." or "Disconnected." or both as seen in example.

Comment: Getting emails to work on localhost has always been infinitely difficult. To make it somewhat easier I would advise using a tried and tested mail class.

Comment: Please don't use the mail() function. Gmail must be transmitted over a secure connection (TLS). Better use "PHPMailer" or "Swift Mailer" or "zend-mail".

Answer (score 0):

> 18/10/23 13:14:54 ** Authenticating as gazchamber.music@gmail.com

Email Id from which account is being sent

> 18/10/23 13:14:52 ** To: gazchamber.music@gmail.com
>
> 18/10/23 13:14:52 ** From: marekpatras@seznam.cz

You cannot use a different email id using your account credentials.

In addition to code, this step is specially for Gmail, where you need to enable setting in order to send mails. Account [setting](https://myaccount.google.com/security?utm_source=OGB&utm_medium=app&pli=1#connectedapps) page, make sure to enable this:
[image]

Comment: Heh, your answer is triggering the chrome translate feature for some reason.

Comment: @Script47, nope that wasn't me, have a close look at OP's mail log

Comment: Thank you, have not had it set for my email i was using in example, but unfortuantely it still doesnt work -> logs the same message.